# How to get vertical lines in legend key using ggplot2 for geom_pointrange() type graphic

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

**UPDATE:  The question is moot.  The vertical lines in the legend key are now default for geom_pointrange() in ggplot2.**

For ggplot2 graphics that have a symbol for a point estimate and a vertical line representing a range about that estimate (95% confidence interval, Inter-quartile Range, Minimum and Maximum, etc) I cannot get the legend key to show the symbol with a **vertical** line.  Since `geom_pointrange()` only has arguments for `ymin` and `ymax`, I would think the intended (default) functionality of `geom_pointrange(show_guide=T)`  would be to have vertical lines (I say default because I understand that with `coord_flip` one could make horizontal lines in the plot).   I also understand that having vertical lines in the legend key when the legend position is right or left will have the vertical lines "run together"...but for legends in the top or bottom having a vertical line through the symbol means that the key will match what appears in the plot.

Yet the approaches I've tried still put horizontal lines in the legend key:

```
## set up
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
ru <- 2*runif(10) - 1
dt <- data.frame(x   = 1:10, 
                 y   = rep(5,10)+ru, 
                 ylo = rep(1,10)+ru, 
                 yhi = rep(9,10)+ru,
                 s   = rep(c("A","B"),each=5),
                 f   = rep(c("facet1", "facet2"), each=5))
```

Default `show_guide=T` for `geom_pointrange` yields desired plot but has horizontal lines in legend key where vertical is desired (so as to match the plot):

```
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_pointrange(aes(x     = x, 
                      y     = y, 
                      ymin  = ylo, 
                      ymax  = yhi, 
                      shape = s), 
                  size=1.1,
                  show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

An attempt with `geom_point` and `geom_segment` together yields desired plot but has horizontal lines in legend key where vertical is desired (so as to match the plot):

```
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_point(aes(    x = x, 
                     y = y, 
                 shape = s), 
             size=3,
             show_guide=T)+
  geom_segment(aes(   x = x, 
                   xend = x, 
                      y = ylo, 
                   yend = yhi), 
               show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

An attempt with `geom_point` and `geom_vline` together yields **desired legend key** but does not respect the `ymin` and `ymax` values in the plot:

```
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=s), show_guide=T, size=3)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi ), show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

How do I get the legend key of the 3rd graph but the plot of one of the first two?

Comment: I filed this issue https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1389.  Currently ggplot2 on CRAN is Version: 1.0.1, so we'll see if v1.0.2 addresses this.

Comment: The vertical lines in the legend key are now default for geom_pointrange() in ggplot2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution involves plotting a vertical line with `geom_vline(show_guide=T)` for an x-value that is out of the bounds of the displayed x-axis along with plotting `geom_segment(show_guide=F)`:

```
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=s), show_guide=T, size=3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ylo, yend=yhi), show_guide=F)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=-1, show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.5,10.5))
```

[image]

The solution with `coord_cartesian()` for a numeric x axis is fine but `facet_grid(scales='free_x')` can be problematic:

```
# problem:  coord_cartesian with numeric x and facetting with scales=free_x
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=s), show_guide=T, size=3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ylo, yend=yhi), show_guide=F)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=-1, show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.5,10.5))+
  facet_grid(.~f, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

So in that situation, another solution that might not apply in every situation, but change x values to some meaningful character of factor and then adjust the xlim:

```
## hack solution: adjust xlim after change x to factor or character 
## (carefully -- double check conversion):
dt$x <- factor(dt$x)
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, shape=s), show_guide=T, size=3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ylo, yend=yhi), show_guide=F)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=-1, show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.5,5.5))+
  facet_grid(.~f, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having to use `grid` to draw the plot, you can manipulate the guide grobs directly:

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
ru <- 2*runif(10) - 1
dt <- data.frame(x   = 1:10, 
                 y   = rep(5,10)+ru, 
                 ylo = rep(1,10)+ru, 
                 yhi = rep(9,10)+ru,
                 s   = rep(c("A","B"),each=5),
                 f   = rep(c("facet1", "facet2"), each=5))

ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_pointrange(aes(x     = x, 
                      y     = y, 
                      ymin  = ylo, 
                      ymax  = yhi, 
                      shape = s), 
                  size=1.1,
                  show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") -> gg

gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
gt <- ggplot_gtable(gb)

seg <- grep("segments", names(gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]]$children))
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]]$children[[seg]]$x0 <- unit(0.5, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]]$children[[seg]]$x1 <- unit(0.5, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]]$children[[seg]]$y0 <- unit(0.1, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[4]]$children[[seg]]$y1 <- unit(0.9, "npc")

seg <- grep("segments", names(gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[6]]$children))
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[6]]$children[[seg]]$x0 <- unit(0.5, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[6]]$children[[seg]]$x1 <- unit(0.5, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[6]]$children[[seg]]$y0 <- unit(0.1, "npc")
gt$grobs[[8]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[6]]$children[[seg]]$y1 <- unit(0.9, "npc")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: @hrbmstr to get your code to run, is `gg <-     
ggplot(data=dt)+
  geom_pointrange(aes(x     = x, 
                      y     = y, 
                      ymin  = ylo, 
                      ymax  = yhi, 
                      shape = s), 
                  size=1.1,
                  show_guide=T)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")` ?